# shipping boxes sizes find largest side and smallest size

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

I am doing some shipping calculations. I need some help trying to figure this out.
Basically, I have a generic list of products with Length, Width, and Height properties.

I would like to EASILY look at the products and find the largest values of all three properties.
From here, I can do some math and figure out the box size based on the # of products.

My initial thought would be to make 3 arrays and find the max of each. Just wanted to see if there was a simpler or cooler way I didnt' know.

Comment: Will you be packing multiple sized products into this box? Do you have fixed size boxes?

Comment: multiple sized products, no fixed box size

Comment: Just to be clear, you have a list of products (each with a W X H X D) that need to be shipped and you want to calculate a box size for optimally packing them all? This is not an easy problem to solve without a box size because there are infinite solutions available, for example - just lay them all out end to end and make a box to cover it. :)

Comment: right, but i'm trying to find the highest value length (that will be the length) finding the largest width (that will be the width) then adding the heights.

Comment: Then you'll get an unnecessarily tall box when shipping only small items. Worst- case if you get a homogeneous list of small items, you will need a REALLY tall box :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an array of arrays. As you read each element (box) from your data source (SQL Server, XML, etc), create an 3-member array and insert the attributes in order of size. Then, add the three-member array to an array of arrays. You can then sort the array of arrays by the first, second or third member using LINQ or some other function.

```
Box1,2,2,3
Box2,5,10,1
Box3,8,4,7
```

Becomes:

```
{  {10,5,1},  {8,7,4},  {3,2,2}  } // First
```

or

```
{  {8,7,4},  {10,5,1},  {3,2,2}  } // Second
```

or

```
{  {8,7,4},  {3,2,2},  {10,5,1}  } // Third
```

Then, you can sort the array by the first element, second element, etc.

You could easily build an array of arrays in a single statement using LINQ, but exactly how you would do so depends on the data source. Assuming you have an class named `Box` with three parameters, `Length`, `Width` and `Height`, and that you have created a strongly-typed collection containing instances of this class:

```
class BoxSorter {

    public IEnumerable<Box> Boxes {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    class Box {
        public double Height {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public double Width {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public double Length {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public void Initialize() {

        this.Boxes = new List<Box>( new Box[] { 
            new Box() { Height = 2, Length = 2, Width = 3 },
            new Box() { Height = 5, Length = 10, Width = 1 },
            new Box() { Height = 8, Length = 4, Width = 7 }
        } );

    }

    public void Sort() {

        var l_arrayOfArrays =
            this.Boxes.Select(
            // Create an array of the Height, Length and Width, then sort the array elements (largest to smallest)
                b => new double[] { b.Height, b.Length, b.Width }.OrderByDescending( v => v ).ToArray()
            );

        var l_dimension1 =
            l_arrayOfArrays.OrderByDescending(
            // Sort the array of arrays by the first (and largest) dimension
                a => a[0]
            );

        var l_dimension2 =
            l_arrayOfArrays.OrderByDescending(
            // Sort the array of arrays by the second (and middle) dimension
                a => a[1]
            );

        var l_dimension3 =
            l_arrayOfArrays.OrderByDescending(
            // Sort the array of arrays by the third (and smallest) dimension
                a => a[2]
            );

    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, this is basically what I did to solve the issue. Thought I'd mark this so other folks would know. This problem was a nightmare since there wasn't a set box size. I also had to add a parameter for weight and go by both item/box size and weight.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need to do is to have a set of box sizes and THEN try packing them optimally in one or more boxes of that size.

[This](http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/lightmaps/) is a simple packer for the 2D case, you can extend this to 3D.

Your algorithm will sorta look like

```
    foreach box in boxes (ordered by decreasing volume)
        while there are unpacked items
            if box has space
                pack item
            else
                box = another box of the same size
```

Now you can decide what to do with unused space in the last box - either pick them all out and try a smaller box, or try packing all items in all size boxes and then pick the combination that results in least number of boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You are really having a problem finding the min, max, and middle of three numbers?

It does not make sense to take the smallest of each column as if you had just two
4 x 4 x 4
8 x 8 x 2
You would incorrectly conclude the smallest is 4 x 4 x 2 and the largest is 8 x 8 x 4.

```
        double[] dimensions;

        dimensions = new double[] {8,7,7};
        Array.Sort(dimensions);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dimensions[0]);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dimensions[1]);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dimensions[2]);

        dimensions = new double[] { 7, 9, 8 };
        Array.Sort(dimensions);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dimensions[0]);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dimensions[1]);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dimensions[2]);
```

P.S. I agree with anathonline that it is way more complex than just simple math if you want an optimal box size and how to pack the items.

Comment: While that is quite trivial - I believe it isn't what the OP needs to solve his/her problem. Finding the optimal packing configuration for a set of cuboids isn't a trivial problem by any means.

Comment: @ananthonline OK I will concede that optimal cuboid may be non trivial.  But that was not that stated question.  OP stated "From here, I can do some math and figure out the box size based on the # of products."  OP did not ask for optimal box size.

Comment: Hence, my comments under the original post trying to determine what the OP wanted to do instead of what he asked for.

Comment: @ananthonline My theory is possibly they wanted an answer to what seemed like the wrong question.  I have had people question my question when it is really the question I meant to ask.  A agree with your comments.